# Tipo numérico, não consigo fazer um range

Tags: r

Boa tarde. Estou fazendo um simples range, e me retorna NA. Alguma dica?

```r
is.numeric(df_1$VLR_FTRMTO)
#[1] TRUE
range(df_1$VLR_FTRMTO)
#[1] NA NA
head(df_1$VLR_FTRMTO)
#[1] 36627192 13165967 63455580 10001774 16173720 75503974
typeof(df_1$VLR_FTRMTO)
#[1] "double"
```

Comment: Tente `range(df_1$VLR_FTRMTO, na.rm = TRUE, finite = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta ter um NA no vetor para que range retorne `c(NA, NA)`.

O exemplo mínimo é esse.

```
vetor <- c(1, NA, 3)
range(vetor)
# [1] NA NA
```

Para corrigir isso, use o argumento `na.rm`. Assim

```
range(vetor, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 1 3
```